# Is it possible to import an Excel spreadsheet, including the comments and hyperlinks, into a List?

Tags: 2007, list, excel, import, hyperlink

I would like to import a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet into a SharePoint 2007 List. The spreadsheet contains comments and hyperlinks. Could those also be imported in the List?

Comments I know would probably not be possible, but what about hyperlinks, would those be retained? What could be a work-around to getting the comments added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments cannot be imported into a SharePoint list. A possible work around might be to add a "comments" column with multiple lines of text (append text optional) The trade off would be that you could only comment on the row.

You also might be able to mimic "comment like" functionality using jQuery. If you are interested in that approach I suggest posting a new question specifically about using jQuery to mimic comments.

Hyperlinks sometimes have trouble importing into SharePoint.  If you experience an error, create a column of the type "hyperlink". Edit the list in datasheet view and copy / paste the hyperlinks.